# Is there a way to enable/setup ESNI in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, sni

I was looking around for a way but I've only got that Nginx does implement the normal SNI and that's it.

Can it be that ESNI is still a "not yet ready" feature for Nginx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ESNI (or ECH, as it's now called) is [not supported by OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7482), it can't be supported by nginx, either.

Comment: So I guess that now it's a matter of waiting